# iPhone : Unable to send Tweets using Twitter+OAuth

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, twitter-oauth

I am using Twitter+OAuth in my app.

But I am getting following error in my NSLog.

```
  Request E0B47D37-CE8C-406A-867E-2133E2469397 failed with error Error Domain=HTTP Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.)"
```

Coding : .h file

```
 #import "SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.h"
 #import "SA_OAuthTwitterController.h"

 @interface FirstViewController: UIViewController <SA_OAuthTwitterControllerDelegate,SA_OAuthTwitterEngineDelegate> 
 {
 SA_OAuthTwitterEngine *_engine;    
 }
```

Coding in : .m file

```
#define kOAuthConsumerKey  @"consumer_key"
#define kOAuthConsumerSecret @"consumer_secrect"

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {


    if(!_engine)
   {
        _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
        _engine.consumerKey = kOAuthConsumerKey;
        _engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;
   }
 }

-(IBAction) buttonPressed
{
  if(![_engine isAuthorized])
        {
            UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate:self];

           if(controller)
            {
              [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"twitter msg : %@",twitterMessage);
            [_engine sendUpdate:twitterMessage];

               UIAlertView *alert  = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Twitter" message:@"Post Successful" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }

  }
}


 #pragma mark SA_OAuthTwitterEngineDelegate

  -(void) storedCachedTwitterOAuthData: (NSString *)data forUsername: (NSString *)username
  {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:data forKey:@"authData"];
        [defaults synchronize];
  }

  -(NSString *) cachedTwitterOAuthDataForUsername: (NSString *)username
  {
        return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authData"];
  }

   #pragma mark TwitterEngineDelegate

   -(void) requestSucceeded: (NSString *) requestIdentifier
   {
        NSLog(@"Request %@ succeeded", requestIdentifier);
   }

   -(void)requestFailed: (NSString *) requestIdentifier withError:(NSError *)error
    {

        NSLog(@"Request %@ failed with error %@",requestIdentifier,error);
    }
```

What could be problem ?

Comment: It's "Tweets", not "Twits". **Now** I see why Twitter decided to do the trademark thing...

Comment: ^ +1 I was about to say the same thing. I'm tempted to call them twits at times though. :/

Comment: Looks like an 401 Unauthorized. We are going to have to see how you are connecting (Code) to help you

Comment: It doesn't really answer your question, but have you considered using ShareKit? http://getsharekit.com

Comment: @devang:dude even i m having the same problem did u find a solution for dis..if u have cud u help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating new cosumerKey and secretKey may solve your problem.And sometimes server at twitter may also don't respond so twit may not post

Answer (score 1):

AS far your coding part is concerned everything is fine unless you used your actual consumer key,Even i faced the same problem.I generated different consumerKey and secretKey and dat did it

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the #define statements at the top of your .m file to use your actual consumer key and consumer secret?